# Action of complex conjugation on Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, complex-numbers, time-reversal-symmetry

Consider a finite-dimensional non-relativistic QM system with hamiltonian $H$. Let $K$ denote the complex conjugation operator. What does $K H K$ simplify to, if the system is: (a) spin-zero; (b) spin-half? I'm thinking it's maybe $H^*$ or $-H^*$, where asterisk denotes complex conjugation (not hermitian adjoint). Please note that we're doing ordinary QM (not QFT). (As a side question: references for where to read about how to deal with anti-linear operators like $K$ would be welcome, as they are hard to find.)

Comment: What is "the complex conjugation operator"? Complex conjugation is *not* a linear operator (it fails to commute with scalars) and therefore not a matrix. The expression $KHK$ is *ill-defined* unless you say explicitly what you mean by it.

Comment: You're right that $K$ is not a linear operator, so of course it can't be represented as a matrix. Indeed, that is why I noted that it's an anti-linear operator. You can google that or check Sakurai QM if you haven't heard of it (or any discussion on things like time-reversal operators): http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Antilinear.html

Comment: I understand what an anti-linear map is. Is $KHK$ just supposed to denote "first apply complex conjugation, then apply $H$, then apply complex conjugation again"? That's a linear map, so you can express it as a matrix, and you can figure out its entries by looking at what it does to a chosen basis. What problems do you have in figuring out what it is?

Comment: Your suggestion probably works, but I just don't know how to proceed, since taking matrix elements of $KHK$ involves using $K$ to act on (basis) vectors, and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Given an abstract Hilbert space and an algebra of linear operators on it, complex conjugation is not defined on the operators. You can define an antilinear map by, for example, specifying a basis whose vectors are left invariant, and then its effect on all other vectors and operators is defined by that. We can choose one such map and call it complex conjugation, if desired.

If the Hilbert space is constructed in terms of complex-valued functions $\psi(x)$ as usual in non-relativistic QM (where $x$ can be any list of variables), then complex conjugation is usually understood to be the antilinear map that leaves all real-valued functions $\psi(x)$ invariant. Then the complex conjugate of any operator, say $H$, is the operator $H^*$ for which 
$$
H^*\psi^*(x)=\big(H\psi(x)\big)^*
\tag{1}
$$
for all $\psi(x)$. This definition is unambiguous because (in the given construction) every state-vector can be represented as $\psi^*(x)$ for some $\psi(x)$ and because we already know how to evaluate the right-hand side because the operator $H$ is given. So  equation (1) tells us how $H^*$ affects every state-vector, which specifies $H^*$ unambiguously. So if we find any operator $H^*$ that satisfies (1), then it's the correct "complex conjugate" of $H$.

In particular, if $H$ is described as a differential operator with complex-valued coefficients, then the preceding definition says that $H^*$ is obtained just by complex-conjugating all of the coefficients. "Coefficients," of course, includes any coefficients that are buried inside matrix notation, such as Pauli matrices.

Beware, though, that when complex conjugation is defined in this seemingly-natural way, it can become unnatural-looking when we switch to some other basis. For example, if we express the same model in the "momentum basis" by writing $\psi(x)=\int dp\ \exp(ipx)\phi(p)$, then the effect of the same "complex conjugation" map on $\phi(p)$ is **not** $\phi^*(p)$, and if $H$ is re-expressed as a differential operator in this new basis, then $H^*$ will generally **not** be obtained just by complex-conjugating its coefficients. This illustrates the point of the first paragraph.

Here's a reference:

- "Anti- (Conjugage) Linearity," https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.06545

Comment: "You can define an antilinear map by, for example, specifying a basis whose vectors are left invariant, and then its effect on all other vectors and operators is defined by that." Can you clarify --  in this context, what does left-invariant mean? Also, I was thinking of a spin space, which is why I said finite-dimensional in my original post, in case that makes a difference in any of your wavefunction remarks.

Comment: Oh, sorry - I didn't mean left-invariant. I meant that the given map leaves them invariant. :)  For a spin-space, my wavefunction example is less relevant, but the principle is the same. For example, take a 2-d Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$. We can define an antilinear map by $w|1\rangle+z|2\rangle\to w^*|1\rangle+z^*|2\rangle$, and this in turn defines how the map affects all linear operators. But this map does _not_ act as $z|\psi\rangle\to z^*|\psi\rangle$ in general. It looks like ordinary "complex conjugation" only in that one special basis.

Comment: "and this in turn defines how the map affects all linear operators". Did you mean "affects all vectors"?

Comment: @Nahsik Both, actually. It defines the effect on all vectors, and therefore it also defines the effect on all linear operators $H$ via $H^*|\psi\rangle^* = (H|\psi\rangle)^*$.

Comment: @DanYand *You wrote* $H^*|\psi\rangle^*=(H|\psi\rangle)^*$ I would
prefer $H^*|\psi\rangle=(H|\psi\rangle^*)^*$. For a wider treatment see
my answer to follow.

Comment: @ElioFabri  I agree: the way you wrote the equation is more comprehensible.